# Uncaught (in promise): Template parse errors: Can't bind to 'routerLink' since it isn't a known native property

Tags: typescript, angular

Following error occurs while routing to another component. here is my code and I am using angular 2 beta 17. I already added all the necessary scripts n the index page. kindly help me out. I will be very thankful to you.

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {MvcComponent} from "./components/mvc.component";
import {Location} from 'angular2/platform/common';
import {Router, RouteDefinition, RouteConfig, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES} from "angular2/router";
import {ChartComponent} from "./components/chart.component";
import {ChartsComponent} from "./components/charts.component";
import {Bootsrtap2Component} from "./components/bootstrap2.component";

import {BootstrapJavascriptComponent} from "./components/bootstrapjavascript.component";


@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    templateUrl: './appScripts/layout/sidebar.html',
    directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES]
})

    @RouteConfig([

        {
            path: '/chart',
            name: 'Chart',
            component: ChartComponent
        },
        {
            path: '/charts',
            name: 'Charts',
            component: ChartsComponent
        },
        {
            path: '/index',
            name: 'Index',
            component: MvcComponent,
            useAsDefault: true
        },
        {
            path: '/components',
            name: 'Components',
            component: Bootsrtap2Component
        },
        {
            path: '/javascipt',
            name: 'Javascipt',
            component: BootstrapJavascriptComponent
        }
    ])

export class AppComponent {
    Profileimageurl: string = './images/flat-avatar.png';
    public routes: RouteDefinition[] = null;
    constructor(private router: Router,
        private location: Location) {

    }

    getLinkStyle(route: RouteDefinition) {
        return this.location.path().indexOf(route.path) > -1;
    }
}
```

### Error Image

[image]

Comment: `routerLink`s are used in the `sidebar.html` page?

Comment: yes routerLinks are used in sidebar.html

Comment: Try adding import {RouterLink} from '@angular/router';

Comment: I tried but issue remains the same

Comment: Have you also added it in the `directives` of the child-components?

Comment: Have you added router js file on the index page?

Comment: if anyone have this issue you could navigate to this solution:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/41277407/3887342

you need to add `RouterModule` to the import of all your modules.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Template parse errors: Can't bind to 'routerLink' since it isn't a known property of 'a'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41268477/template-parse-errors-cant-bind-to-routerlink-since-it-isnt-a-known-propert)